# How to replace requirejs with almondjs with a yeoman Gruntfile.js?

Tags: requirejs, yeoman, almond

So I created a project using yeoman init and it uses requirejs, I wish to replace requirejs with almondjs to make it load faster. How can I do this?

AlmondJS is here: https://github.com/jrburke/almond

RequireJS is here: http://requirejs.org/

Yeoman: http://yeoman.io/

---

The only mention of require.js in Gruntfile.js is:

```
// rjs configuration. You don't necessarily need to specify the typical
// `path` configuration, the rjs task will parse these values from your
// main module, using http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#mainConfigFile
//
// name / out / mainConfig file should be used. You can let it blank if
// you're using usemin-handler to parse rjs config from markup (default
// setup)
rjs: {
  // no minification, is done by the min task
  optimize: 'none',
  baseUrl: './scripts',
  wrap: true,
  name: 'main'
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are using Yeoman 1.0 and not an earlier version. It uses grunt-requirejs which has almond support. rjs was used in versions before 1.0.

See documentation at https://github.com/asciidisco/grunt-requirejs/blob/master/docs/almondIntegration.md. It appears that all you may need to do is add `almond: true` to the options for requirejs in your Gruntfile (or not depending on what you want to do--again see the documentation).

Comment: Hi, but there's no requirejs in my Gruntfile, I mean - yeoman generates a Gruntfile.js with the only require mentioned is:

Comment: rjs was used in Yeoman prior to 1.0. Start with Yeoman 1.0 and it should be replaced with grunt-requirejs. At least that's my understanding.